# Maven Install Error in vaadin10

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10

I am working on Vaadin 10 which uses Maven,when i do maven Install,I get below error in console,I have check all compiler configuration,I am new to Maven so please help me out :

```
[INFO] Building My Starter Project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements:iron-ajax:jar:2.1.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ my-starter-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ my-starter-project ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:testResources (default-testResources) @ my-starter-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 17 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ my-starter-project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 30 source files to C:\Capdes\Vaadin10\vaadin\my-starter-project\target\test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.583 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-23T10:57:58+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/362M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------


 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project my-starter-project: Compilation failure
    [ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Did you follow the instructions? https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/introduction/tutorial-get-started.html

Comment: is your JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE?, check java and maven setup : https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/JDK_Howto.html, https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/